# how can I play a video by file path (saved in photo gallery) using AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayer? - xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, avplayer, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

Actually, I am capturing video using AVCaptureSession+AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and then storing file path in SQLite. Now I want to play recorded video using that file path.
so, my question is how can I play a video by file path (saved in photo gallery) using AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayer?
I am working in xamarin.ios

Comment: MPMoviePlayerViewController are obsolete after iOS 9.0 . For AVplayer you could check https://xamarinmonkeys.blogspot.com/2018/06/avplayer-in-xamarin-ios.html

Comment: above blog post shows how to play an embedded video.

Comment: They are the same . What you need to do is replace the path as you want .

Comment: ``` asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(Case.Path)); ``` is not working for me

Comment: although file path is file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/87CE0DBA-2C01-4476-B7C7-C3AE0DE1B077/tmp/e62909dc-530c-48ee-81af-d8317cfa5f74.mov

Comment: You could provide the sample so that I can test it on my side .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use PhotoKit to first request access to the photo gallery, then you can query and get a PHAssetCollection with the images/live images/videos you are interested in.

With a PHAsset in your hand you can use PHImageManager to request a AVAsset to display in your video player.